# Intval weird result

Tags: php

Intval gives me a weird result:

```
var_dump($coords[0]); //string(45) "4370065.628494422"
var_dump($coords[1]); //string(47) "5457273.078928657"

$rw = "4370065.628494422"; 
$hw = "5457273.078928657"; 

var_dump($rw); //string(17) "4370065.628494422"
var_dump($hw); //string(17) "5457273.078928657"

var_dump(intval($coords[0])); //int(0) <-- Why is that 0
var_dump(intval($coords[1])); //int(5457273)

var_dump(intval($rw)); //int(4370065)
var_dump(intval($hw)); //int(5457273)
```

Why is intval($coords[0]) 0?

$coords is the result of a soap request

Comment: `string(45)` should be a hint. you don't have anywhere NEAR enough digits to account for 45 characters. there's probably html or somethign in there that's being rendered. do a view-source on your page to check.

Comment: See the length .. string(45) vs string(17) .. Your $cords posses more symbols(perhaps hidden).. I recommend you to sanitize them before you make the intval.. Either with preg_replace or filter_var..

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
intval(filter_var($coords[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION));
intval(filter_var($coords[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION));
```

it now works. Thank you @Svetlio